# Generate differing length vectors of sequentially paired values from end to start

Tags: r, vector, binary-tree, parent, children

Apologies if this question has already been asked before - I was struggling to think of how to phrase my searches (hence the awkward title)!

What I have is a data frame of single-character values, like so:

```
-------------------------
|  Parent  |  Daughter  |
-------------------------
|     A    |     B      |
|     B    |     C      |
|     B    |     D      |
|     A    |     E      |
-------------------------
```

Where for every parent there will always be two daughters (like a complete binary tree). I'm trying to write a segment of code that will produce the vectors of paths from the top parent down to the final daughters:

```
A B C
A B D
A E
```

But with varying numbers of parents, and varying lengths of vectors.

I thought about using a for loop but came unstuck because I think I'd need one for every 'level' of the tree, which I don't know in advance.

I don't necessarily want the code, just advice on how to go about such a problem! But any help would be hugely appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** I should point out that the 'from end to start' is just because I figure that way would be easier - it's certainly not necessary!

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Parent = c("A", "B", "B", "A"), Daughter = c("B", "C", "D", "E"))
```

**EDIT2:** Here are some more examples of the desired result. If I made the table a little bigger, so that:

```
-------------------------
|  Parent  |  Daughter  |
-------------------------
|     A    |     B      |
|     B    |     C      |
|     B    |     D      |
|     A    |     E      |
|     C    |     F      |
|     C    |     G      |
|     E    |     H      |
|     E    |     I      |
-------------------------
```

Data 2:

```
df <- data.frame(Parent = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "E", "E"), Daughter = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))
```

Then the vectors I'd want would be:

```
A B C F
A B C G
A B D
A E H
A E I
```

Comment: can you add more examples of the desired result?

Comment: Why is the daughter named "B" like the parent? Isn't that confusing for an  example?

Comment: I've added some more examples, as requested! So B is both the daughter of A and the parent of C and D, so that A > B > C and A > B > D.

Comment: okay got you there!

Comment: Your Data 2 contains an error! -> `"H""`. remove one `"`

Comment: Oops, my bad, thanks!

Comment: What is the next step? Maybe you need `igraph::graph_from_data_frame(df)`

Comment: I have not come up with a solution yet. I would try to stratify the tree into layers. topLayer: A, 2nd-layer: B, C ... etc

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that could be helpful:

```
parent <- "A"
lev <- df$Daughter[which(df$Parent == parent)]
output <- cbind(parent, lev)
while(length(lev) > 0){
    lev <- df$Daughter[which(is.element(df$Parent, lev))]
    output <- cbind(output, lev)
}
# which returns
> output
     parent lev lev
[1,] "A"    "B" "C"
[2,] "A"    "E" "D"
```

This could easily be translated into a `function(parent)`:

```
myfct <- function(parent){

  lev <- df$Daughter[which(df$Parent == parent)]
  output <- data.frame(parent, lev, stringsAsFactors = F)

  while(length(lev) > 0){

    dat <- df[which(is.element(df$Parent, lev)),]
    newdat <- merge(x = output, y = dat, by.x = "lev", by.y = "Parent", all = TRUE)

    col.first <- which(names(newdat) == "parent")
    col.last <- which(names(newdat) == "Daughter")
    col.sec.last <- which(names(newdat) == "lev")
    col.rest <- setdiff(1:dim(newdat)[2], c(col.first, col.sec.last,col.last))

    newdat <- newdat[, c(col.first, col.rest, col.sec.last, col.last)]
    names(newdat)[2:(length(names(newdat))-1)] <- paste0("x.",2:(length(names(newdat))-1))
    names(newdat)[length(names(newdat))] <- "lev" 


    output <- newdat

    lev <- df$Daughter[which(is.element(df$Parent, lev))]
  }
  cols <- as.numeric(which(!sapply(output, function(x)all(is.na(x)))))
  output <- output[,cols]
  return(output)
}
```

And here one can apply the function:

```
parents.list <- unique(df$Parent)
sapply(parents.list, myfct)
# which returns
$A
  parent x.2 x.3  x.4
1      A   B   C    F
2      A   B   C    G
3      A   B   D <NA>
4      A   E   H <NA>
5      A   E   I <NA>

$B
  parent x.2  x.3
1      B   C    F
2      B   C    G
3      B   D <NA>

$C
  parent x.2
1      C   F
2      C   G

$E
  parent x.2
1      E   H
2      E   I
```

Now you can always modify it in order to change the structure of the output.

---

**Edit**

The key is do add a `while`. I edited my code and now it ought to work without having to specify the number of levels.

Comment: This looks like this ticket! It's not quite working on my machine (for example in the output A is the parent of B and E, while B is the parent of C and D), but this is almost certainly the way forwards. Thanks so much!

Comment: I noticed you updated your data, so I'm still adjusting the code. I'll keep you posted if I come up with something.

Comment: @DanAdams I came up with something that should work, see the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Using *igraph* package, convert dataframe to graph object, get the paths, remove paths that are subset of other paths.

```
library(igraph)

# example data
df <- data.frame(Parent = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C", "E", "E"), 
                 Daughter = c("B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"))

# convert to graph object
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)

# get all the paths, extract node ids from paths
res <- all_simple_paths(g, from = "A")
res <- lapply(res, as_ids)

# get index where vector is not subset of other vector
ix <- sapply(res, function(i) {
  x <- sapply(res, function(j) length(intersect(i, j)))
  sum(length(i) == x) == 1
})

# result
res <- res[ix]
# res
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "F"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "G"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "A" "B" "D"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "A" "E" "H"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "A" "E" "I"
```

Comment: Nice, I really should check out that `igraph` package

Comment: I have detected some talent here!

Comment: Hugely impressed by both of these answers - thanks a lot guys! Wish I could accept both of them.